# EF Poco Generate for specific table

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, visual-studio, t4

It is possible to generate a `POCO` class for one selected table in entity framework.

There are  few tools that does that, but it does generate for all the table,

The primary reason i am asking this is to generate a `POCO` class for a single table, and add attributes to it manually, and the all i need to do is to attach it to `DbContext` as a property :).

As for example using Package-manager, they way it is done to add migration

```
generate-poco TableName FileName.cs
```

Comment: You may create own utility accepting "TableName" as parameter around: [Database Schema Reader](https://dbschemareader.codeplex.com/) . Is this something what you are looking for?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the ADO.Net wizard to generate the POCO classes for you from the database. The wizard will generate one partial class per table with properties that match your field names.  Here is what I've done in the past when I wanted to add a new large table to an existing code first context.

1. Add->New Item -> ADO.Net Entity Data Model
2. Move the generated POCO classes to some other folder (and edit the namespace)
3. Delete the rest of the extra stuff (I.e the .edmx file and generated context)
4. Add the DBSet to 'your' DBContext

If you are using EF migrations

5. add-migration
6. update-database

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of extensions for visual studio for that.
EF 4.x POCO Entity Generator for C# Free (try this one and you only need to map the table)